# VB .Net 2008 - List all objects currently in scope?

Tags: .net, reference, object, scope

Please can any one advise me if there is an object in .net that can be used to get a list or references to all objects that are currently in scope for an object. For example if the code is currently executing in a method, what objects declared in this method are currently instanciated and alive and what objects that are declared at class level have been instanciated already and are alive?

Also I know I can test each object declared explicitly for a null reference, but I am looking for something that is more generic (perhaps using reflection?) that can be used from any method to clear up all alive objects.

Thanks in advance,

Best regards,
Duane.

Comment: Not possible without a debugger/profiler.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think this information can be retrieved. If it were available, it would probably be available through the [`System.GC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.aspx) class – but it isn’t.

Reflection can only get you so far – you can inspect objects and with a bit of trickery even local declarations in methods, but you’ve got no easy way of knowing which contexts are active. A stack trace can yield the required information for the (current thread’s) call stack, but this will ignore all static variables in the current application domain (and the [`System.AppDomain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) class doesn’t allow access to this information either).