# Alive objects during lifetime of a .NET application

Tags: .net

During the lifetime of a .NET application, at a given point of time , I want to understand following:
1. What are the list of objects that are alive in the memory?
2. What is the exact size of each object?
3. Who is holding references to each object?

Also, During the execution of a .NET application, whenever any object is created, I immediately want to know about it. At the same time, I also want to know what is its size?

Comment: This is not a site where you "want" something. This is a site where you are stuck trying and need help. So what did you try on your own so far?

Comment: I googled for all alive objects and i found following. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912683/vb-net-2008-list-all-objects-currently-in-scope does a profiler or debugger is neccesary?

Comment: These are things you can find out with Windbg, using the SOS debugger extension.  You need a really good reason to do this, there's a fairly steep learning curve.  A dedicated .NET memory profiler is invariably the friendlier tool.  Scratch any idea to do this from your own program, the GC internals are off-limits and programs cannot debug themselves.

Comment: Questions 1-3 can be answered through the SOS debugger extension. Allocations can be traced via CLR events. However, keep in mind that the answers to these questions are quite data heavy. Instead of trying to collect all the data you can think of, it might be better to focus on a specific problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way of working with the .net object tree is to use external memory profiler. In general, you attach the profile to your app and then browse the object graph by interacting with the UI of the profiler or executing command. Consider my article about the subject http://alexatnet.com/articles/net-memory-management-and-garbage-collector